# Menstrual cycle and luteinizing hormone (LH)

Tags: menstrual-cycle

What is the effect of increased concentration of LH on the follicle at the start of the menstrual cycle?

I know that increased levels of FSH at the beginning causes follicles to mature and release estrogen, but I cannot seem to be able to find what the effect of increased levels of Luteinizing Hormone at the beginning of the cycle would have.

Comment: Do you mean the preovulatory LH surge?

Comment: If the preovulatory LH surge occurs at the beginning of the menstrual cycle, then yes that may be what the question is referring ro.

Answer (score 1):

> Luteinizing hormone (LH): A hormone released by the pituitary gland in response to luteinizing hormone- releasing hormone. It controls the length and sequence of the female menstrual cycle, including ovulation, preparation of the uterus for implantation of a fertilized egg, and ovarian production of both estrogen and progesterone. Theca cells in the ovary respond to LH stimulation by secretion of testosterone, which is converted into estrogen by adjacent granulosa cells. **In women, ovulation of mature follicles on the ovary is induced by a large burst of LH secretion - the preovulatory LH surge**. Residual cells within ovulated follicles proliferate to form corpora lutea, which secrete the steroid hormones - progesterone and estradiol. Progesterone is necessary for the maintenance of pregnancy, and, in most mammals, LH is required for continued development and function of corpora lutea.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3136063/